# Importing google-cloud.storage on Vue3

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vuejs3

I'm trying to import @google-cloud/storage in my vue3 project... but I get this error:

[image]

This is how I added the @google-cloud/storage in my code.
[image]

Just follow the instruction from this site: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs

I just want to successfully import @google-cloud/storage in my Vue3 project.